# C++ Making My Own Library

Tags: visual-studio, include, header-files

I have been writing my own library wrapper for Win32. I want to have it as an easily accessible library I can include in my projects.

Currently I have to manually add all the files to the project I am creating, then add the code:

```
#include "..etc/somefolder/frzn_windows.h"
```

Is there a way I can setup Microsoft Visual Studio 13 to automatically link the folder I store "frzn_windows.h" in, and also so I don't have to add each .h/.cpp file to the project. Similar to how it knows "windows.h" or < string>, etc.

I don't want the library to be a .dll or anything, just code that includes a bunch of classes to make it easier to use the Windows API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **Additional Include Directories** feature, that is accessible through project's [Property Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/669zx6zc.aspx). See official Microsoft documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73f9s62w.aspx) for details.

Comment: Ok, so I got Additional Include Directories working. I was also to just add it to VC++ Directories property page Include Directories. Though, both solutions have to be manually done for each new project I create. Is there a way to set it up for all new projects by default?

Comment: See if [this feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xkh1wxd8.aspx) can help. Also take a look at [CMake](http://schneide.wordpress.com/2013/03/26/building-visual-c-projects-with-cmake/).